Restful Sensor Gives No State Value
I am trying to use vaules from an API i have tested the API with postman and the data structure i recieve back is below (irrelevant values removed but structure maintained)
{
    "data": {
        "api_token": "fd3b6366e28fdc77e8c12fe8ff2a7425",
    },
    "devices": [
        {
            "did": "KlkvwRNNnJNQC4bEnE1uSf",
        }
    ],
    "message": "Authorization Successful!"
} 

I then use the following inside “/homeassistant/configuration.yaml”
rest:
  - resource: "https://MYURL/login"
    scan_interval: 172000
    method: POST
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
    payload: '{
      email: "MYEMAIL@gmail.com",
      password: "MYPASS"
    }'
    
    sensor:
      - unique_id: 22c32b5b-8c0c-4995-8a38-2838f78ac147
        name: "hottub_login_api"
        value_template: "{{ value_json }}"

          
      - unique_id: ba9f0dcb-6c49-47c6-b6d1-c4a0c9900a32
        name: "hottub_login_did"
        value_template: "{{ value_json }}"

When i lookup the sensor in developer tools it has no value
previous to this i have also tried the followng but they always result in the sensor being in an unavalible state
    sensor:
      - unique_id: 22c32b5b-8c0c-4995-8a38-2838f78ac147
        name: "hottub_login_api"
        value_template: "{{ value_json['data']['api_token'] }}"

-----OR-----
    sensor:
      - unique_id: 22c32b5b-8c0c-4995-8a38-2838f78ac147
        name: "hottub_login_api"
        value_template: "{{ value_json.data.api_token }}"

-----OR-----
    sensor:
      - unique_id: 22c32b5b-8c0c-4995-8a38-2838f78ac147
        name: "hottub_login_api"
        value_template: "{{ value_json }}"
        json_attributes_path: "$.data"
        json_attributes:
          - api_token

Please help, is my initial rest not working am i missing somthing from the post, how can i debug the initial POST or is there somthing else i am doing wrong?

I used the following command, this allowed me to see the raw output
value_template: "{{ value[:205] }}"

i was then able to determine that the whitespace in the payload caused the issue
